# problem execute tests with java spring boot in order

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

Hello everyone please someone help me to solve this problem i have done my project with java spring boot unit test with annotation of ***@order(value=x)*** the problem is when i execute those tests it  executes with a wrong order that i have defined them with value=1 ,value=2,... ,at least i have 7 tests and i need them to be executed with order, besides i work with intellij please someone have an answer.

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots, but as formatted text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service; therefore, it’s expected that you [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question by including a [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We advice to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Unsure since the screenshot is cut in the wrong place (you shouldn't use picture for code btw) but it seems that `@TestMethodOrder` on the class is set to `Random` (can only see "Ran" so guessing here).

This needs to be `@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)` for the `@Order` annotation on tests to work.

**EDIT**

This would only work in JUnit 5. Here is an example of working ordering in test (kotlin but it is the same princpple in Java):

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest

@SpringBootTest
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation::class)
internal class MyTest {

  @Test
  @Order(value = 2)
  fun test2() {
      println("2")
  }

  @Test
  @Order(value = 3)
  fun test3() {
      println("3")
  }

  @Test
  @Order(value = 1)
  fun test1() {
      println("1")
  }
}
```

Also note that the import. You might have imported a Spring @Order or another one that might not work

Comment: thank s mister grekier i did just an annotation of @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class) but  the problem is always with the wrong order i worked with intellij

Comment: Did you remove `@FixedMethodOrder` ?

Comment: I also assumed you were using JUnit 5, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes i have left just one annotation of Method order but the same problem :(

Comment: yes am using junit5 why ?

Comment: which junit should i work with please ?

Comment: I updated the response. JUnit 5 is fine.

Comment: thank you so much mister grekier finally it works ^^